# Angular images in css don’t load when css dynamically added

Tags: angular

I’ll try to explain my dilemma the best I can.

So in the app I’m not using the assets folder I have my icon images in app/img/icons/ and say I have a component called “home” I can load the icon in the scss file like this:

background: url(../img/icons/test.png);

This works fine, but my dilemma comes when I dynamically add a style tag to the html and try to do the same thing, the images can’t be found. So I’m adding the style tag into the same component html document.

I’ve noticed from the web inspector that it looks like angular does something with the images when compiling, like it moves them into the root folder and it’s almost as though it doesn’t include images in the build if you’ve not used them before it’s built - if that makes sense.

So I’m wondering how I can add dynamic css to the html document and allow it to load the background images? It just seems to ignore them if not used before build unless I’m misunderstanding the structure of the final build?

Basically after the dynamic style is added to the document you have something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lqZd.jpg)

And the image doesn’t load yet the exact same code works fine in the components scss file!

Comment: stackblitz please.

Comment: Do you actually _need_ to load the actual stylesheet from a backend? Normally what one does in this situation is to prepare the stylesheet ahead of time and have some rest service give you data that lets you choose which classes or templates to apply to something. Dynamically adding a `<style>` tag is _very un-idiomatic_ in Angular.

Comment: Yes I do. I’m building an app using angular that’s an upgrade from a current app done with jwuery mobile so  im learning angular as I go. The app gets information and style information via an external api we built as it has a control panel to style the app so the css comes in dynamically, but only for certain aspects of the app. In this case it’s loading customised tiles for a dashboard from the api as html with generated css from the server. So the app has 6 built in tiles and the admin can add more via the control panel which generates the html output. If you have a better way I’m all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `app/img/icons/` to your "assets" array in your angular.json

Comment: Why though? I don’t need to do that when using the images in the components sass file before compile. It’s almost like angular reads the sass and only compiled in the images that have been used before building.

Comment: That is pretty much true. Angular's router needs to know that you are actually trying to access assets and not a route.